# Sequence contains no elements - PayPal SOAP Response

Tags: xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am trying to read the value from an XML element but I always get "Sequence contains to elements" error.
I already done my research but nothing works for my problem.

I want to read the Ack and Timestamp element values in this XML

```xml
<DoDirectPaymentResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
    <Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2014-09-16T04:41:56Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Success</Ack>
</DoDirectPaymentResponse>
```

Here's my code for reading the Ack and Timestamp values

```cs
String xmlString = @xml;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
       XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);

       var timestamp = xdoc.Descendants("Timestamp").Single();
       receipt.Timestamp = timestamp.Value;

       var response = xdoc.Descendants("Ack").Single();
        receipt.Response = response.Value;
}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use proper `XNamespace` to access elements in the namespace :

```cs
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
XNamespace ns = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents";

var timestamp = xdoc.Descendants(ns+"Timestamp").Single();
receipt.Timestamp = timestamp.Value;

var response = xdoc.Descendants(ns+"Ack").Single();
receipt.Response = response.Value;
```

Side note: you can use [`XDocument.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load XML from XML string content.

Comment: You know what, I have already tried that but IT IS WEIRD that it works this time. Thanks very much for your help and also for the XDocument.Parse().